Disabling Power Apps Button while Running a Flow in Power Automate
I´d like to disable a PowerApps Button that runs a Flow in Power Automate (just while the Flow is loading), I want to avoid duplicity (double clicks) when sending files through that specific button.
I know how to disable buttons, but I do so only after the flow ended, not during it.
Once the Flow finished, the button should be available again in Power Apps.
Is that possible?
Rookie user here,
Thanks!

You can do the following steps:

Set a variable in PowerApps UpdateContext({Enable_btn: true})

In your flow, add a step (after your current last step), Respond to PowerApps and return a variable. E.g. Response as true.

Set the OnSelect property of your button as:
// This disables the button
UpdateContext({Enable_btn: false});

// Enable button when flow is finished 
UpdateContext({Enable_btn: Run.Your_FlowName().Response = "true")};


Set your button's DisplayMode as
If(Enable_btn,
   DisplayMode.Edit,
   DisplayMode.Disabled)



NOTE: The only drawback is if your flow ran more then 120 sec, then you have a timeout error as this the default MAX time limit to get response from as flow.
